# Upgrade Python 3.x to the newest stable version?

Tags: python, windows, upgrade

Is there a way to upgrade Pyhton 3.x to the newest stable 3.x version on Windows, if the current version was installed using msi standalone installer?

In my case I'm trying to upgrade 3.5.3 to 3.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python most major versions are released as separate package. For instance, Python 2.6, Python 2.7, Python 3.1 all live in separate packages on Ubuntu.

You'll have to install 3.6.0 as a separate package.